# UISearchController change color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I use this code to change my navigation bar appearance which I put it in AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: "E1354A")
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Also I use UISearchController which I add programmatically. But when I push it the color of navigation bar and search controller are changed in black. I don't understand why it happens and how I can prevent it?

[[image]][1

[image]

Comment: Did you check in viewController, you have not give color to self.navigation ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. I put in viewDidLoad:

```
   let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "E1354A")
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    let searchField = searchController.searchBar.searchTextField
    searchField.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
```